# How to eliminate the use of this class variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, logging

Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Windows 8.1 Update, PostgreSQL 9.3.3

I have built an XLog class that allows me to write records to PostgreSQL from within any controller in my application.  However, it's built around the use of a class variable.  I am wondering whether I can convert this to an instance variable.

In the ApplicationController, I instantiate the class variable and write the first record:

```
  @@xaction = XLog.new
  @@xaction.info(
      controller: self.class.name,
      action:     "start",
      status:     "success"
  )
```

At any point in the application, I can reference @@xaction.info with a hash to log the success or failure of any transaction.  It works...

XLog is:

```
class XLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  def info hash
    logger.info "XLog " << hash.collect { |key, value| "#{key}: #{value}; "}.join  # map?
    XLog.create(
        controller: hash[:controller],
        associate:  hash[:associate],
        proxy:      hash[:proxy],
        object:     hash[:object],
        value:      hash[:value],
        action:     hash[:action],
        status:     hash[:status],
        message:    hash[:message]
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an instance variable in the class scope:

```
class << self

  def xaction
    @xaction ||= XLog.new
  end

end

def xaction
  self.class.xaction
end

xaction.info(
      controller: self.class.name,
      action:     "start",
      status:     "success"
)
```

If I have my Ruby right this should allow you to access xaction from within a controller method as `xaction`, or from anywhere as `ApplicationController.xaction`.

---

EDIT: Perhaps a cleaner solution

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
before_filter :start_log
def start_log
  XLog.info(
      controller: self.class.name,
      action:     "start",
      status:     "success"
  )
end




#app/models/x_log.rb
class XLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.info(hash)
    @logger ||= Xlog.new
    @logger.info hash
  end

  def info(hash)
    logger.info "XLog " << hash.collect { |key, value| "#{key}: #{value}; "}.join  # map?
    XLog.create(
        controller: hash[:controller],
        associate:  hash[:associate],
        proxy:      hash[:proxy],
        object:     hash[:object],
        value:      hash[:value],
        action:     hash[:action],
        status:     hash[:status],
        message:    hash[:message]
    )
  end
end
```

Just use XLog.info(hash) wherever you want. You can add some syntactic sugar to the application controller if you like.

Comment: @A Fader Darkly.  To clarify, you would say to put all of this code in ApplicationController and then reference it in each controller as xaction?  Or, in models or views as ApplicationController.xaction?

Comment: If you want to keep this behaviour in the ApplicationController, yes. It feels like it should do its own initialisation though, and just be referenced in the ApplicationController for convenience. See the singleton idea by @maringan.

Comment: I've added a less obtrusive solution for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Xlog should call in Singleton class:

```
class Log
  include Singleton

  def info(hash)
    Xlog.create(
        controller: hash[:controller],
        associate:  hash[:associate],
        proxy:      hash[:proxy],
        object:     hash[:object],
        value:      hash[:value],
        action:     hash[:action],
        status:     hash[:status],
        message:    hash[:message]
    )
  end
end
```

and you can use in application controller `around_filter`:

```
 around_filter :wrap_actions

 def wrap_actions
    x_log = Log.instance
    begin
      yield
      x_log.info(hash_success)
    rescue
      x_log.info(hash_fail)
    end
  end
```

Comment: I love the use of singleton to avoid mess and the around_filter. You appear to be missing the logger.info line however, and I'm not sure why you're assigning Xlog.create(...) to Xlog.

Comment: I think this is the right direction?  Can an edit resolve the issues?